# Aptana Studio 3 Limit search in App Explorer

Tags: search, aptana3

If I use the search under "App Explorer" the search will parse any file type (also images) so the search is very slow.
How can I exclude this files without using the dialog search?

Comment: To the folks voting to close as off topic, please re-read the [FAQ]: "...if your question generally covers...[snip]...software tools commonly used by programmers". This includes how to use IDE's and programmers editors.

Comment: You could use a regular expression to avoid including certain file extension results in your search, but I don't think you would see a huge speed increase. What is wrong with using the search dialog? Or perhaps you don't need to keep a ton of images in your Aptana project?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you using filters in this case. 
Go to

```
Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filter.
```

Add there a filter for example to

**Exclude all**

**Files**

**Name matches : *.jpg**

or 
**Name matches : *.png**

or anything that makes your search slower in this case and what is not useful for you at all.
This way you will exclude all resources that are not useful for you in the entire App Explorer window.